# KrbError: ('Principal not found in keytab', -1)

Tags: python, kerberos

I am trying to test the principal of the `keytab` file by using this code:

```
import kerberos
principal = kerberos.getServerPrincipalDetails('HTTP/testdc.testing.gc', 'TESTING.GC')
```

I got the keytab as a environment variable: `export KRB5_KTNAME=/etc/key_tab_file`
And the content of this keytab:

```
^E^B^@^@^@T^@^B^@
TESTING.GC^@^DHTTP^@^Qtestdc.testing.gc^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^C^@^R^@ ▒-▒~A\ڳ▒^H▒F▒xb^C^X▒Gy▒q▒▒I▒▒▒~^▒~UDd
```

But I keep constantly receive an `KrbError: ('Principal not found in keytab', -1)` after trying to initiate it.

This step is described as part of the `flask-kerberos` initialize processes:

https://github.com/mkomitee/flask-kerberos/blob/master/flask_kerberos.py#L33

What am I doing wrong? I tried various of options as the `service` and the `host` arguments of this method, nothing worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue, it suppose to be only the service name (`http`) and the DNS\DC server (`testdc.testing.gc`).